# Run a transform on any subform of a form that is a call to a function in clojure.zip

Tags: macros, clojure, clojurescript

Well, the title is a mouthful, so I will expand on it. I have the following code (it is incomplete, mostly just for illustration):

```
(use '[clojure.zip :only [up down right node])

(defn in-zip? [form]
  (contains? (-> 'clojure.zip ns-publics vals set) (first form)))

(defn do-something-to-zip-form [fx loc rest]
  ;; this is where I would do the transform, but for now, I will just
  ;; return the actual form
  form)

(defn transform-zip [form]
  (if (in-zip? form)
    (do-something-to-zip-form form)
    form))

(defmacro gozip [body]
  (clojure.walk/postwalk transform-zip body))
```

The purpose of `in-zip?` is to take a form and determine whether the evaluated form calls to a function in `clojure.zip` . So, something like `(is-zip? '(clojure.zip/down loc)` or `(is-zip? '(up loc))`  should return `true`, any form that isn't calling a function within `clojure.zip` should return `false`.

I want to be able to call `gozip` with a form, and have every call to a function in `clojure.zip` be replaced by my `do-something-to-zip-form` transformation. Some examples:

> (gozip (-> loc down right right (clojure.zip/update 3))

In the above expression, I would like it to run the transform in 5 places (`loc`,`down`,`right`,`right`, and `update`) because those are all functions within `clojure.zip`.

> (gozip (let [d (down loc)] (node loc)))

In the above expression, I would like to run transform in 2 places (`down`, `node`).

Sorry about being so pedantic about explaining what I am interested in, it is just that I am having trouble explaining exactly what I want, seems easier through examples. I am looking to use gozip in clojure and clojurescript code.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to intercept calls to the `clojure.zip` functions to alter their behavior - if that's the case, check out the Robert Hooke library: https://github.com/technomancy/robert-hooke

Comment: Thank you. I will give that a look at. I should mention that I am looking to use gozip under clojurescript as well, so I added a mention of that.

Comment: To do what you want I believe you'll need a code-walker.  See http://blog.fogus.me/2013/07/17/an-introduction-to-deep-code-walking-macros-with-clojure/ for an example of how to do this.